# Javascript File Not Found in Browser but Compiles Correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I went through a React Introduction found on Microsoft Virtual Academy and downloaded the code found in the associated GitHub [repo](https://github.com/sayar/ReactMVA/tree/master/02_ReactIntroduction/Code/end). At this point I'm just trying to have my simple Index.html page create an empty React Div Tag.

However i'm having trouble establishing my environmentI installed node.js, downloaded the start code from github, did my npm install and upon compile got the error "Breaking Change: Its's not longer allowed to omit the '-loader' when using loaders. You need to specify the file-loader instead of file. I fixed this error by changing the webpack.config.js .html loader under module from "file?name=[name].[ext]" to "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]".

However upon doing that I received an error stating "Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename" error when compiling. I fixed this error by changing the output filename in the webpack.config.js from bundle.js to [name].js.

Then it compiled fine but when looking at it in the browser I noticed that there was an error stating "the server has not found anything matching the requested URI" and mentions app.js.

I have tried changing the call in my Index.html to app.js but also get the same error.  I have tried clearing out the code in my app.js so it is completely empty and still get the requested URI error.  Below is my very simple code...

```
webpackag.config.js`var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  entry: {
    javascript: './app.js',
    html: './index.html'
  },
  output: { 
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Code for Index.html...`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pizza Bot Manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.Js code below...

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>         
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, Document.getElementById("main"));
```

`
Very new to React so if anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this error I would really appreciate it

Error as it appears in the Browser Console

HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8080/app.js

Comment: You say the error mentions 'bundle.js', but I don't see bundle.js referenced anywhere in your code. Could you post the entire error that you see in the browser? Also, you could try to change [name].js back to bundle.js, and remove the html  property under `entry`

Comment: @hansn thank you for your review.  I was trying a few things including bundle.js and just calling the specific js file from my Index.html which is what is is currently.   I have edited the post to include the error from the console and also updated my post to remove the reference to bundle.js and changed it to app.js

Comment: @hansn also i tried your suggestion of removing the html property under entry, changed the output filename property to bundle.js from [name].js and then updated the Index.html to refer to ./bundle.js and compiled.  I get the same 404 error except the GET portion of the error states http://localhost:8080/bundle.js

Comment: I think you're outputting to /dist/app.js (or /dist/bundle.js - whatever file name you chose.

Comment: @Patrick Thats what I thought as well but from Index.html I tried going to src = /app/dist/bundle.js but still no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the /app, just /dist/bundle.js

Comment: @hansn i continued to try your path by removing the html file.  The good part is when I compile I now see the bundle.js as part of what is compiling.  However the bad part is now when I navigate to the page the page says "Cannot GET /".  I'm assuming that is because the HTML page itself is not part of the compile?

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the fast reply.  When I try what you mentioned I get the following...HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
localhost:8080
Current window: localhost
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js

Comment: OK looks like by changing webpack.config.js with brackets around my input files it solved the Request URI is not defined problem...

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like adding brackets around my input files in the webpack.config.js seemed to resolve the 404 error.  See updated "entry" code below for resolution to help others who may have this issue...

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  /*entry: {
    html: './index.html',
    javascript: './app.js'
  },*/
  entry: ['./index.html','./app.js'],
  output: { 
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```